# This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for PersonalizedAdConsent.framework is missing or could not be read

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

The title error is what gets emailed after uploading the ipa via the application loader and below is the error that occurs in debug mode:

> ERROR: "The framework
>   APPNAME.app/Frameworks/PersonalizedAdConsent.framework does not
>   contain a binary named PersonalizedAdConsent"

I've been getting this error in debug mode when trying to build the project. However, when I build it in Ad-Hoc mode, it builds fine and uploads on the application loader without any issues but then I get the following mail

> "This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   PersonalizedAdConsent.framework is missing or could not be read."

I've looked in the `Info.plist` file as well as `.csproj` file for this reference and I cannot find it anywhere.

Also searched online, can't find much about the `PersonalizedAdConsent`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Right click on your project->options->iOS build ->Linker Behavior ->Don't link

Comment: @LucasZ Tried all three options for linker.. all don't work

Comment: Hi i have the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AndersBootsmannLarsen the problem was the nuget package Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds and another one that referenced "Ads", think it's "Xamarin.Firebase.Ads". Just remove the packages that have "Ads" in it if they're not needed and then upload the new file that you re-build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the issue was because of the following packages:
Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds

&

Xamarin.Firebase.Ads

As far as I can tell, the app needs permissions to request consent to display ads or personalized ads (not too sure exactly) and it build correctly after removing these packages.

These were in a build that I've done on Windows for a different app which did not actually use them but VS for MAC gave me the issues and it turned out to be these packages that were causing it.

Hope it helps!